# What server log file(with Centos5) must I check to locate specific IP activity?

Tags: file, centos, logging

I leasing a dedi server under Centos5, just recently I ve setup a blog website that grabs feeds from other news websites and presents them on my blog.
Some days after I see high server loads that cant be coming just from the cron jobs that I run every now and then to grab feeds from other websites for my blog website.

Thats why I m trying to pico some log files in order to have a better look the whole problem.
These last days I noticed(from statscounter service) the same IP address visiting my blog website many times per day so I want to find out what us trying to do.

I tried looking in all /var/log log files and httpd too but no luck.

**Is there any other log file I should open or any other procedure to track this IP acivity on server?**

Answer (score 1):

Searching your log files from a text editor isn't too efficient... there are several things you can do... here are a few:

This will list the entries for the IP Address in question (replace ip.add.re.ss with the actual IP address that concerns you, make sure to place it within the quotes):

```
find /var/log/ -exec grep "ip.add.re.ss" '{}' \; -print
```

This will list the 10 IP addresses that hit your apache access log the most, sort them, and list the number of times that particular IP address hit your site:

```
cat /var/log/httpd/access_log |awk '{print $1}'|cut -d? -f1|sort -n|uniq -c|sort -n|tail -10
```

This will list the ten most accessed files on your site, sort them and display the number of times that file was accessed:

```
cat /var/log/httpd/access_log |awk '{print $7}'|cut -d? -f1|sort -n|uniq -c|sort -n|tail -10
```

You can google "apache log analyzers" or "search apache logs" for additional options.

Answer (score 0):

you can monitor network traffic from this host (of course not the traffic from the past):

```
tcpdump -w out.dmp host a.b.c.d
```

and examine the result with wireshark.